# consulta en mongoDB con json anidado

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, nosql

buen día.

tengo la siguiente colección en mongoDb:

```
{
"signupDate": "2018-11-22T19:14:02.047Z",
"_id": "5bf700269e5b59276885eda5",
"userName": "pruebas",
"email": "pruebas@gmail.com",
"password": "abc1234",
"interests": "{\"followEmails\": false, \"dogs\": [{\"raza\": \"poodle\", 
\"age\": 2},{\"raza\": \"poodle\", \"age\": 7}]}",
"phone": "00000",
"imgProfile": "img/profile/user.png",
"Emailverify": false,
"passwordHas": 
"$2a$10$y1Wty9OUQUmOB5B90kEDY.DWR6umNgGURznJxkhdpI.pbNGelS/Qe",
"__v": 0
},
```

necesito crear una consulta que me devuelva los usuarios que tienen en su campo interest->dogs = determinada raza de perro.
he intendado ya varias consultas desde robomongo pero aun no doy.

esta consulta me devuelve todos los usuarios que contienen en el objecto interests la clave dogs.

```
db.getCollection('users').find({},{interests: [ "dogs"]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo mi duda si lo que guardas en el campo 'interests' es un objeto JSON (documento en MongoDB) o es un String, en el caso de que fuera String tendrías que cambiar al formato JSON.

En el caso de que sea un JSON, lo que necesitas realizar es una búsqueda de subdocumentos:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({userName: /*user*/ , 'interests.dogs.raza': /*raza*/}, {})
```

Esta consulta buscara en todo los usuarios que indiques en '*user*' que tenga en campo 'interests', dentro el campo 'dogs' y buscara en todo el array de documentos, documento a documento, el campo 'raza' que sea igual al valor '*raza*'.
A partir de hay tendrías que proyectar/filtrar el documento que quieres devolver.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos

Comment: gracias por la ayuda! el campo interest es un objecto. tu consulta me ayudo a aclarar lo que necesitaba.
la consulta final fue esta: 
db.getCollection('users').find({'interests.dogs.raza': /*raza*/ , 'interests.dogs.raza': /*raza*/}, {'interests.dogs.raza': 'pug', 'email': '*'}) .. 
 si te fijas necesitaba proyectar solo el campo interest y el campo emaill. marcare tu respuesta como la correcta